# Why ZeroMQ returns 4,294,967,295 on zmq_recv() SUB socket?

Tags: c++, c, zeromq

I use ZeroMQ in C to build a simple shared variables API in C++. I use a **`REQ`**/**`REP`** socket to share a variable `id` and a **`PUB`**/**`SUB`** socket to share variable data. A server publish every update on a variable in the network.

The client subscribe to the `id` of a variable and should wait for a publication. Instead of waiting, the `zmq_recv()` receives data continuously and the size of the data makes no sense (this should be 1 byte, actually the return value is 4294967295 bytes!).

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: If you assigned the result of `zmq_recv` to a variable of the correct, documented datatype, you'd see that the value is actually `-1` and then you'd simply look up what this means... http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-recv

Comment: Hint: memorise what 2^15, 2^16, 2^31, 2^32, 2^63 and 2^64 roughly look like and then you'll spot these signed/unsigned errors when you make them.

Comment: I do not use this function. The function returns the size of the data read in success, not 0. But this is right, I use an int now and I throw an exception in this case. Here I get "Operation not supported".

Comment: OK I found that I did `zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_PUB)` instead of `zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_SUB)`